# Unable to extract method name in Suds when user is allowed to select a method at run time

Tags: python, methods, introspection, suds

```
from suds.client import Client

from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated

import urllib2

class methodinvokeclass():

    def methodinvokemethod(self,*args):

        method=args[1]         

        c=args[2]

        #method=LatLonListZipCode in the variable above
        response=c.service.method("90210")--How should I make this work ?

        #response=c.service.LatLonListZipCode("90210")
        #The above snippet works, but this not what I want
        #As I want to make it generic "method" and ask user in the run time to select     ---       #methodname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#method constains a string (eg: 'LatLonListZipCode')
method_to_call = getattr(c.service, method)
response = method_to_call("90210")
```

Also, you have to do some error checking in case the method can't be found.